# CKQueryNotification not received on MacCatalyst build

Tags: swift, xcode, cloudkit, mac-catalyst

My app receives `CKQueryNotification` from `CKQuerySubscription` normally on iOS or iPadOS, but with MacCatalyst with the same bundle ID (generated from Xcode 11.6), it never receives `CKQueryNotification` even tho

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken deviceToken: Data)
```

gets called properly upon app launch - whenever there's a record change on CloudKit, the method

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication,
                 didReceiveRemoteNotification userInfo: [AnyHashable : Any],
                 fetchCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping (UIBackgroundFetchResult) -> Swift.Void)
```

never fires on the MacCatalyst build, whereas it fires immediately on iOS.

Any ideas why? There's a thread on Apple forum but don't see a solution yet: https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/125069

Answer (score 1):

For anyone also experiencing this problem while developing your app, I decided to publish the app anyways and found out that in the App Store version, on Mac the catalyst app actually could get the notification almost immediately. So it seems to be a debug environment bug for CloudKit.

Answer (score 0):

You are not sharing enough code for us to help you, so I'll take a guess. Try to define your notificationInfo values as follows and see if that makes a difference. Inside didRegisterForRemoteNotifications:

```
    // This is your subscription object
    let subscription = CKQuerySubscription(recordType: "Subscription", predicate: NSPredicate(format: "TRUEPREDICATE"), options: [.firesOnRecordCreation, .firesOnRecordUpdate])
    
    // Here we customize the notification message
    let info = CKSubscription.NotificationInfo()

    info.shouldSendContentAvailable = true
    info.desiredKeys = ["identifier", "title", "date"]
    info.soundName = ""
    info.alertBody = ""
    info.title = ""
    info.alertActionLocalizationKey = ""

    // Assign the notification info to your subscription
    subscription.notificationInfo = info
```

Comment: Sorry I'm already doing this, and db.fetchAllSubscriptions return the subscriptions correctly